# Streamlit image download button

Tags: python, streamlit

```
st.write("Preview")
#openCV image result cropped_image which is an np array
st.image(cropped_image)
#cropped_image converted to PIL image color      
result = Image.fromarray(cropped_image.astype('uint8'), 'RGB')
    
img = Image.open(result)            

btn = st.download_button(
      label="Download image",
      data=img,
      file_name="imagename.png",
      mime="image/png")
```

I want to use st.download_button to download the image result. I know I cannot use the cropped_image result since it is an np array. I converted the image array to a PIL image but I don't know how I can get the result image filename from here . Could you please give me some ideas how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

The Streamlit `download_button` expects the data type to be a certain type. Read more here: https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/blob/ba46ad297e8816f0d6a3aa910ce67556239f3e6d/lib/streamlit/elements/button.py#L353

You can convert your `PIL` Image to `bytes` using the following snippet:

```
from io import BytesIO
buf = BytesIO()
img.save(buf, format="JPEG")
byte_im = buf.getvalue()
```

Now you can use the `st.download_button`

```
btn = col.download_button(
      label="Download Image",
      data=byte_im,
      file_name="imagename.png",
      mime="image/jpeg",
      )
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the image file in your directory:

```
st.download_button(label='Download Image',
                        data= open('yourimage.png', 'rb').read(),
                        file_name='imagename.png',
                        mime='image/png')
```